# Remove Duplicate Objects from Nested Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this example code here:

```
[
    {
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "96e34264-ed96-4ebd-8d67-3c05071e0920",
                "page": 71,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2bc81905169169007.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/bc8/62e2c2bc81905169169007.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            },
            {
                "id": "96e34266-390f-485c-9b05-65558ba7e33a",
                "page": 72,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/bd5/62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "96e34266-390f-485c-9b05-65558ba7e33a",
                "page": 72,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/bd5/62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            },
            {
                "id": "96e34266-4e66-4f9e-bcb3-e0f6f7da9300",
                "page": 73,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2bd69d9a939178596.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/bd6/62e2c2bd69d9a939178596.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "images": {
            "id": "96e34268-0944-42c4-8012-10d865752d15",
            "page": 74,
            "disk_name": "62e2c2be88bd1122676754.jpg",
            "path": "/images/62e/2c2/be8/62e2c2be88bd1122676754.jpg",
            "language": null,
            "width": 5176,
            "height": 3684
        }
    },
    {
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "96e34267-7522-486a-8c40-d8cfa3a6c29c",
                "page": 75,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2be2e12d354405395.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/be2/62e2c2be2e12d354405395.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            },
            {
                "id": "96e34268-5450-4bca-bb30-21580ce5cb89",
                "page": 76,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/beb/62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "96e34268-5450-4bca-bb30-21580ce5cb89",
                "page": 76,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/beb/62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            },
            {
                "id": "96e34269-2502-42dc-81b4-068efbc7748b",
                "page": 77,
                "disk_name": "62e2c2bf47a5d074519927.jpg",
                "path": "/images/62e/2c2/bf4/62e2c2bf47a5d074519927.jpg",
                "language": null,
                "width": 2588,
                "height": 3684
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I'm trying to remove the duplicate objects that has images already in the first instance of an object. As you can see from the array, the objects either have an `images` property that is either an object or an array of 2 images. The objects with 2 images has a duplicate entry of the previous object's last item unless it's an object with only 1 image.

Besides filtering out the objects with only 1 image I cant seem to use array filter to remove the duplicates.

**Additional Info:** The Array has to remain in the order it is, The goal is to remove the parent object itself not the nested array of objects.

Comment: You don't need to filter, you need to refactor the array. (or filter based on a Set tracking images you've seen already.)

Comment: Agree with pilchard

Comment: The data has no other information in it - does it have to remain nested, or is a flattened array of image objects ok?

Comment: Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. When practical post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) to track which images you've seen already and using it to [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) each `images` property if it is an array. Here [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `images` property from the object, checking if it is an array with [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and filtering it if it is, and finally returning a refactored object.

```js
const input = [{ images: [{ id: '96e34264-ed96-4ebd-8d67-3c05071e0920', page: 71, disk_name: '62e2c2bc81905169169007.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/bc8/62e2c2bc81905169169007.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, }, { id: '96e34266-390f-485c-9b05-65558ba7e33a', page: 72, disk_name: '62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/bd5/62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, },], }, { images: [{ id: '96e34266-390f-485c-9b05-65558ba7e33a', page: 72, disk_name: '62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/bd5/62e2c2bd5c8d6266674368.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, }, { id: '96e34266-4e66-4f9e-bcb3-e0f6f7da9300', page: 73, disk_name: '62e2c2bd69d9a939178596.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/bd6/62e2c2bd69d9a939178596.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, },], }, { images: { id: '96e34268-0944-42c4-8012-10d865752d15', page: 74, disk_name: '62e2c2be88bd1122676754.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/be8/62e2c2be88bd1122676754.jpg', language: null, width: 5176, height: 3684, }, }, { images: [{ id: '96e34267-7522-486a-8c40-d8cfa3a6c29c', page: 75, disk_name: '62e2c2be2e12d354405395.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/be2/62e2c2be2e12d354405395.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, }, { id: '96e34268-5450-4bca-bb30-21580ce5cb89', page: 76, disk_name: '62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/beb/62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, },], }, { images: [{ id: '96e34268-5450-4bca-bb30-21580ce5cb89', page: 76, disk_name: '62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/beb/62e2c2beb58f7660056604.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, }, { id: '96e34269-2502-42dc-81b4-068efbc7748b', page: 77, disk_name: '62e2c2bf47a5d074519927.jpg', path: '/images/62e/2c2/bf4/62e2c2bf47a5d074519927.jpg', language: null, width: 2588, height: 3684, },], },];

const seen = new Set();
const result = input.map(({ images, ...obj }) => {

  if (Array.isArray(images)) {
    images = images.filter(image => {
      if (!seen.has(image.id)) {
        seen.add(image.id);
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    });
  }

  return {
    ...obj,
    images,
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

A slightly terser version of the above using an [AND short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation)

```
const seen = new Set();
const result = input.map(({ images, ...obj }) => (
  {
    ...obj,
    images: Array.isArray(images)
      ? images.filter(image => !seen.has(image.id) && seen.add(image.id))
      : images,
  }
));
```

Comment: I've added a little more additional info if that helps?

Comment: that's fair, but thank you for the help regardless, I have a basline to work off of.